# C# string behaving that like char array

Tags: c#

Is this correct?

```
string a;
a = Console.ReadLine();
for (int i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a[i]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, why wouldn't it?

Comment: Correct in what sense?

Comment: It's not correct and it will crash - see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not correct, because C# strings are not normally terminated with a NUL character.

You need to terminate the loop using `i < a.Length`, not by looking into the array.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike C and C++, strings in c# are not `NUL`-terminated. Instead, you can get its length via the `Length` property. To print each character on a line, you can use:

```
string a;
a = Console.ReadLine();
for (int i = 0; i< a.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a[i]);
}
```

Or alternatively, using `foreach`:

```
foreach(char c in a)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c);
}
```

Also, despite the `a[i]` syntax, strings in .Net are not char arrays, they are (immutable) objects. They might be implemented using char arrays, but that's a different matter. The reason you can use the `a[i]` syntax is because `String` defines an indexer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
string a;

a = Console.ReadLine();

foreach(var c in a)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No it's not correct, because the NUL character is not stored in the `string`. I would do this with a `foreach` statement:

```
string a = Console.ReadLine();
foreach (var myChar in a)
{
    Console.WriteLine(myChar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this will not work. C# strings are **not** `NUL`-terminated. Instead, they store a length property. This is common in garbage-collected languages. As an example, this makes a valid string:

```
string a = "a string ";
a += '\0';
a += " still the same string";
```

What you can do is this:

```
foreach (char c in a)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c);
}
```

or this:

```
for (int i=0;i<a.Length;i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That won't work, because [strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in C# aren't terminated with a null character (`'\0'`), they have a `Length` defined. But yes, you can access it via index like `a[i]` because it provides an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)